# Style carrier, wifi, time and battery in React Native

Tags: react-native

Is there a way to style the very top elements in React Native (carrier name, wifi strength, time and battery)? I currently have an image that fills the screen, so would like to adjust those to be white, but can't seem to find any documentation on how to adjust their coloring/styling.

Thanks!

Comment: Is this on iOS or Android?

Comment: This is for iOS. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a way to style the Statusbar; you can even hide it.
[StatusBarIOS](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/statusbarios.html) has the following methods:

```
static setStyle(style: StatusBarStyle, animated?: boolean) 
static setHidden(hidden: boolean, animation?: StatusBarAnimation) 
static setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible(visible: boolean)
```

What you're looking for is setStyle, which has [StatusBarStyle](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/Components/StatusBar/StatusBarIOS.ios.js) as its first argument. As you can see in the code StatusBarStyle is an enum with the following values:

```
type StatusBarStyle = $Enum<{
  'default': string,
  'light-content': string,
}>;
```

So, either use 0 for black, 1 for white OR 'default' and 'light-content'.

```
StatusBarIOS.setStyle(1);
StatusBarIOS.setStyle('light-content');
```